# How can I calculate overlap integral (J) between fluorescence and UV-Vis spectra in FRET mechanism

Tags: energy, spectroscopy

How can I calculate overlap integral (J) between fluorescence and UV-Vis spectra in FRET mechanism?
I want to use this formula: J=(∫ϵ(⋋) F_D (⋋)  ⋋^4  d⋋)/(∫F_D (⋋)d⋋)
How can I find  ϵ(⋋) for every lambda in suitable range, I only have fluorescence spectrum of donor and uv-vis spectrum of acceptor. How can I calculate this integral.

Comment: You can format mathematical and chemical expressions on chem.SE using MathJax; [this post](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86) contains further details.

Comment: First you have to normalise the fluorescence spectrum to unit area. Then measure/obtain the absorption spectrum in terms of extinction coefficient vs wavelength. The overlap integration is done numerically; usually the fluorimeter and spectrophotometer produce so many points so that summing values is usually ok. (don't forget to multiply by $\delta \lambda$). You must have data at the same wavelength points, otherwise you will have to interpolate one spectrum to produce this. You can obtain $\epsilon$ from a plot of optical density vs concentration. Check your calc with known compounds.